# How are iterations in a loop added to the event queue?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to understand the following piece of code for some time now:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

I have an idea of why it produces the output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

But just wanted to clarify my understanding of how the event loop works in JavaScript.

Is it that each iteration creates an event in the event loop before the `setTimeout` runs?

I know that by default, the `setTimeout` function uses `0` as its `milliseconds` value, but that it only guarantees the *minimum* amount of time that the method will be added to the event queue.

Are the iterations added to the event queue before the `setTimeout` is?

```
[0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [console.log]
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzokr6Boeaw

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Comment: The event queue is not really important here. You could store the functions, call them directly after the loop, and get the same result. See dupe link.

Answer (score 1):

Each message in the **event queue** corresponds to a function. Functions added to queue by your `setTimeout` will be *only triggered after your main function completes*.

As example:

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
    console.log('test')
```

it will output:

```
test
5
5
5
5
5
```